# How to make a member function of a class in C++ generate a different random number each time it is called?

Tags: c++, class, random, constructor, member-functions

I have a class which also includes a random number engine and its distribution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

class C
{ 
  public:
      typedef std::mt19937_64 engine;
      typedef std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution;
      .
      .
      .

  protected:
      engine rng;
      distribution dist;
      void func();
      .
      .
      .
};
```

Since the constructor is called only once, I put the seed in it:

```
C::C()
{   .
    .
    .  
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    distribution dist(0.0, pow(10,12));
    engine rng(seed);
}
```

The following member function is supposed to generate a random number and is going to be called lots of times in a single run of the program:

```
void C::func()
{    .
     .
     .
     double randNum = floor(dist(rng));
     std::cout << randNum << std::endl;      
     .
     .
     .
}
```

However, each time it generates the number 0 as the random number. It seems that `dist(rng)` is not doing its job.

I really need to find the problem and correct the output. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: The code you show for the constructor seems to be creating *local* variables that hide the class members (i.e. you initialize *local variables* and not the *members* used later). Don't do this.

Comment: Basically, remove "distribution" and "engine" from your constructor while keeping the variable names and put them in the initializer list

Comment: @KABoissonneault No, that won't compile. The stuff would have to be in the initializer list.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Oops, and now I forgot to say that if you need want the variable seed you must do an assignment instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You define your `dist` and `eng` variables in the class

```
protected:
  engine rng;
  distribution dist; // Here
  void func();
```

And in the constructor you define another with the same name

```
C::C()
{   .
    .
    .  
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    distribution dist(0.0, pow(10,12)); // Here
    engine rng(seed);
}
```

I assume you want the latter to be an assignment, not a new variable. Then you will get the numbers you want.

```
C::C()
{   .
    .
    .  
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    dist = distribution(0.0, pow(10,12)); // Here
    rng = engine(seed);
}
```

Or with initialization

```
C() : dist(0.0, pow(10, 12)),
  rng(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count())
```

Comment: Why would you copy-assign these? Why not _initialise_?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If they are constants, of course you can if you want. The resulting code will most likely be the same and to my eye this is just clearer and more the way the OP used. Added it also

Comment: I find it less clear, most wasteful, and misleading. It's a case of "why go out of your way to do the wrong thing". Getting into the habit of "initialise unless you can't" is a far better way to go through life. :)

Comment: Thanks @SamiKuhmonen! It worked. But I don't understand one thing. `engine` is a type and `rng` is an object. Why couldn't I write `rng(seed)` in the constructor instead of `rng = engine(seed)`? This `engine`in the latter looks weird to me.

Comment: The compiler will consider `rng(seed)` as a function call, not construction, so it's not accepted. In the initialization it is understood as constructing the object, as is assigning from `engine(seed)`. In the assignment a new object is created and then assigned to the variable, which is why the initialization method should rather be used. (And if my terminology is a bit off, C++ gurus are welcome to correct it)

Answer (score 2):

Sami is close, but you should really be *initialising* these members:

```
C::C()
  : dist(0.0, pow(10, 12))
  , rng(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count())
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor, you're creating a local variable `dist` that hides the class member, while the class member gets default-initialized. A default-initialized `uniform_real_distribution` generates values in the range [0,1), which `floor` will always turn into 0.

Comment: So that was the story... Thanks! :)